# bash break from a read inside trap

Tags: bash

Trying to restore echo when user interrupts a read from this bash shell function that they call from their shell:

```
setsecret() { stty -echo; read $1; stty echo; }
```

If you type ctrl-c during the read, the `stty echo` is not called, so I have to do it manually from the shell. Not a huge deal, but would prefer to not have to do this.

So far I have this:

```
break_from_setsecret() { 
    stty echo
    trap - INT
    echo "Press ENTER alone to cancel command (instead of Ctrl-C, which would mess up your terminal echo)"
}
setsecret() { 
    trap break_from_setsecret INT
    echo "Type in a secret and press ENTER (press ENTER alone to cancel the commmand):"
    stty -echo
    read $1 
    stty echo
}
```

This is a net improvement over having to type "stty echo" while echo is off in the shell. But not perfect:

- the read actually resumes after the handler returns; so you have to press ENTER (per the message I added in handler)
- if instead of pressing ENTER, you type ctrl-c a second time (ie after the handler echo), the shell exits (but if you press enter and the command ends, you can type ctrl-c fine in the shell, everything is back to normal).

I tried cancelling the read by "re-raising" the signal from the `break_from_setsecret` via `kill -n INT $$` but that did not work (it exits my shell). Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, if there was a way to register a cleanup function that `setsecret()` would call when it ends (even from ctrl-c), but I don't think bash supports this. I tried with trap ERR instead of INT but handler does not get called on a ctrl-c during read (eventhough if you ctrl-c during a normal read, the exit code of read is non-zero).

**EDIT**:
Latest workaround is to gobble up the ctrl-c by changing the handler to this:

```
break_from_setsecret() { 
    echo "Press ENTER alone to cancel command (instead of Ctrl-C, which would mess up your terminal echo)"
}
```

But it would still be nice to have the cleanup approach work.

Comment: In `bash`, you should be able to just use `read -s "$1"`, without needing to use `stty` explicitly.

Comment: @chepner nice, that is way better approach that stty echo on/off! I will leave the question open I think, because there are aspects that will be good to know (like trap function for exiting a command, which one answer discusses although it does not work in bash 4.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `trap` on `SIGNT` and `RETURN` to set `stty echo` back:

```sh
setsecret() { 
    stty -echo
    trap 'stty echo; trap - SIGINT RETURN; echo; return' SIGINT RETURN
    read -p 'Type in a secret (pressing ENTER or ctrl-C will cancel this commmand): ' "$1"
}
```

Comment: For me, the handler is not called, in either successful or cancelled read.

Comment: I tested this with bash 5.1.4

Comment: Cool. Note however that the `EXIT` handler will only be called if I call `setsecret` from a script, or the shell that I ran the command in exits. In my case, the trap has to be `RETURN` (which I didn't know about until now). I checked that this works in bash 4.4.

Comment: True, it works when `setsecret` is called within the script itself.

Comment: I added "that they call from their shell" to my question for clarity. If you extend your answer accordingly, I can accept and close this.